# How do set dynamically of a sidebar div

Tags: css

How do I make my sidebars height dynamically so it fills the whole screen.

```css
body, html, .exit-intent-container {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "gothamBook"
}


.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

.fa-angle-down {
    margin-left: 10px
}

.sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 22%;
    height: 170%;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.exit-intent-header {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.exit-intent-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.exit-intent-header-wrapper {
    padding: 1px 0 1px 0;
}

.exit-intent-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.exit-intent-inner {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <form id="sideBarForm">
                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Layout</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>

                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Background:
                        <ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
                            <li>
                                Image: <input type='file' id='getval' name="bgImage" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                color:
                                <!-- {
                                    input:document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"),
                                    changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper',
                                    cssProperty:'width',
                                    pixels:true
                                }, -->
                                <input type="color" class="backgroundColor" value="#ffffff" name="bgColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'background', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <br/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Exit intent width:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentWidth" name="width" value="450" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Exit intent Height:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentHeight" name="height" value="450" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'height', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Font-family:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily" name="fontFamily" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'fontFamily', pixels:false})">
                            <option value="abel">Abel</option>
                            <option value="alegreya">Alegreya</option>
                            <option value="arvo">Arvo</option>
                            <option value="dosis">Dosis</option>
                            <option value="gothamBlack">Gotham Black</option>
                            <option value="gothamBook">Gotham Book</option>
                            <option value="gothamMedium">Gotham Medium</option>                        
                            <option value="openSans">Open Sans</option>
                            <option value="oswald">Oswald</option>
                            <option value="playfair">Playfair</option>
                            <option value="titillium_web">Tititlium</option>
                            <option value="yellowTail">Yellow Tail</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Close btn type:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily exitIntentCloseBtn" name="closeBtn" onchange="changeCloseBtn(this)">
                            <option value="close-btn-one">Type 1</option>
                            <option value="close-btn-two">Type 2</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Insert image:<br><input type='file' id='getimgval' name="bgImage" /><br>
                        image width: <br><input type='text' class='imgWidth' onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.layoutImg', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})"/><br>
                        position: <br>
                        <select class="imagePosition" name="imgPos" onchange="changeImgPosition(this)">
                            <option value="bottom-left">Bottom left</option>
                            <option value="bottom-right">Bottom right</option>
                            <option value="upper-right">Upper right</option>
                            <option value="upper-left">Upper left</option>
                            <option value="inline">Inline</option>
                            <option value="on-top">On top of each other</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Text</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>

                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Header background color:
                        <input type="color" class="headerBGColor" name="headerBGColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header-wrapper', cssProperty:'backgroundColor', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Header:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentHeader" name="headerText" value="Header" onchange="changeText(this, '.exit-intent-header')">

                        <input type="color" class="headerColor" name="headerColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Header underline
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="underlineText" name="headerUnderline" onchange="setUnderline()">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Header font-size:
                        <br>
                            <input type="number" class="exitIntentHeaderFontSize" name="headerFontSize" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'fontSize', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Description:
                        <br>
                        <textarea type="text" class="exitIntentDescription" name="descriptionText" value="Register now to be the first to get all the updates" onchange="changeText(this, '.description')"></textarea>
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Description color:

                        <input type="color" class="descriptionColor" name="descriptionTextColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.description', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Font-size:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentFontSize" name="fontSize" value="17" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'fontSize', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Font-alignment:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily exitIntentAlignment" name="fontAlignment" onchange="changeFontAlignment(this)">
                            <option value="left">left</option>
                            <option value="middle">middle</option>
                            <option value="right">right</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Spacing & Border-radius</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Padding-Exit intent:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingAll" name="padding" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'padding', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Padding-body All:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPadding" name="paddingBody" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'padding', pixels:true})">
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        Padding-body top:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPadding" name="paddingBody" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingTop', pixels:true})">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Padding-body left:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingLeft" name="paddingLeft" value="20" onchange="changeStyling([{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingLeft', pixels:true},{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'paddingLeft', pixels:true}])">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Padding-body right:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingRight" name="paddingRight" value="0" onchange="changeStyling([{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingRight', pixels:true},{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'paddingRight', pixels:true}])">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Margin top form body (Input & Btn):
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="formMargin" value="70" name="margin" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-body', cssProperty:'marginTop', pixels:true})">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Body border radius:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentRadius" name="borderRadius" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'borderRadius', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Form</strong> <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        How many input fields?
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" value="2" class="inputQuantity" name="inputNumber" onchange="calculateInputs()" min="1" max="5">
                        <div class="formFieldInputs"></div>
                        <div class="btnAddinputs"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Type of form (presets):
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentForm" name="typeOfForm" onchange="changeForm()">
                            <option value="onTop" selected>on top of each other</option>
                            <option value="inline">inline</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button text:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="btnText" name="btnText" value="Inschrijven" onchange="changeText(this, '.button')">
                        <input type="color" class="btnTextColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" value="#ffffff">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button width:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnWidth" name="btnWidth" value="300" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button height:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnHeight" name="btnHeight" value="40" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'height', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button color:
                        <br>
                        <input type="color" class="btnColor" name="btnColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'backgroundColor', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" value="#00CABA">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button radius:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnRadius" name="btnRadius" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'borderRadius', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Add privacy policy
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" class="privacyPolicy" name="privacyPolicy" onchange="showPrivacyPolicy()">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anchorlinks"></li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Exit intent html</strong>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <textarea cols="35" rows="10" class="html-viewer"></textarea>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-save btn-first" onclick="saveSettings()">Save settings</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-first" onclick="getHtml()">Get exit-intent html</button>
                </li>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Exit Intent -->
    <div class="exit-intent-container" style="margin-left: 20%;">
        <div class="content-overlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; background-color: #000; opacity: .5;"></div>

        <div class="exit-intent-wrapper">
            <span class="close-btn" onclick="closeExitIntent()"></span>
            <div class="exit-intent-content-wrapper">
                <div class="exit-intent-header-wrapper">
                    <h1 class="column exit-intent-header">Test</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="exit-intent-inner" style="font-size: 24px;">
                    <p class="column description">Register now to be the first to get all the updates</p>
                    <div class="exit-intent-body">
                        <div class="column">
                            <form action="" class="form">
                                <div class="inner-form">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="column">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="email-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <button class="button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you could try `min-height: 100vh` if your sidebar is the height of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing height to '100vh' adding overflow: auto, position: fixed, and that should do it like this:

```css
body, html, .exit-intent-container {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "gothamBook"
}


.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

.fa-angle-down {
    margin-left: 10px
}

.sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.exit-intent-header {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.exit-intent-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.exit-intent-header-wrapper {
    padding: 1px 0 1px 0;
}

.exit-intent-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.exit-intent-inner {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <form id="sideBarForm">
                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Layout</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>

                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Background:
                        <ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
                            <li>
                                Image: <input type='file' id='getval' name="bgImage" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                color:
                                <!-- {
                                    input:document.querySelector(".exitIntentWidth"),
                                    changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper',
                                    cssProperty:'width',
                                    pixels:true
                                }, -->
                                <input type="color" class="backgroundColor" value="#ffffff" name="bgColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'background', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <br/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Exit intent width:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentWidth" name="width" value="450" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Exit intent Height:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentHeight" name="height" value="450" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'height', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Font-family:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily" name="fontFamily" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'fontFamily', pixels:false})">
                            <option value="abel">Abel</option>
                            <option value="alegreya">Alegreya</option>
                            <option value="arvo">Arvo</option>
                            <option value="dosis">Dosis</option>
                            <option value="gothamBlack">Gotham Black</option>
                            <option value="gothamBook">Gotham Book</option>
                            <option value="gothamMedium">Gotham Medium</option>                        
                            <option value="openSans">Open Sans</option>
                            <option value="oswald">Oswald</option>
                            <option value="playfair">Playfair</option>
                            <option value="titillium_web">Tititlium</option>
                            <option value="yellowTail">Yellow Tail</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Close btn type:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily exitIntentCloseBtn" name="closeBtn" onchange="changeCloseBtn(this)">
                            <option value="close-btn-one">Type 1</option>
                            <option value="close-btn-two">Type 2</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Insert image:<br><input type='file' id='getimgval' name="bgImage" /><br>
                        image width: <br><input type='text' class='imgWidth' onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.layoutImg', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})"/><br>
                        position: <br>
                        <select class="imagePosition" name="imgPos" onchange="changeImgPosition(this)">
                            <option value="bottom-left">Bottom left</option>
                            <option value="bottom-right">Bottom right</option>
                            <option value="upper-right">Upper right</option>
                            <option value="upper-left">Upper left</option>
                            <option value="inline">Inline</option>
                            <option value="on-top">On top of each other</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Text</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>

                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Header background color:
                        <input type="color" class="headerBGColor" name="headerBGColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header-wrapper', cssProperty:'backgroundColor', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Header:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="exitIntentHeader" name="headerText" value="Header" onchange="changeText(this, '.exit-intent-header')">

                        <input type="color" class="headerColor" name="headerColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Header underline
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="underlineText" name="headerUnderline" onchange="setUnderline()">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Header font-size:
                        <br>
                            <input type="number" class="exitIntentHeaderFontSize" name="headerFontSize" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'fontSize', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Description:
                        <br>
                        <textarea type="text" class="exitIntentDescription" name="descriptionText" value="Register now to be the first to get all the updates" onchange="changeText(this, '.description')"></textarea>
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Description color:

                        <input type="color" class="descriptionColor" name="descriptionTextColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.description', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Font-size:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentFontSize" name="fontSize" value="17" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'fontSize', pixels:true})">
                        <br>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Font-alignment:
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentFontFamily exitIntentAlignment" name="fontAlignment" onchange="changeFontAlignment(this)">
                            <option value="left">left</option>
                            <option value="middle">middle</option>
                            <option value="right">right</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Spacing & Border-radius</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        Padding-Exit intent:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingAll" name="padding" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'padding', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Padding-body All:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPadding" name="paddingBody" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'padding', pixels:true})">
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        Padding-body top:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPadding" name="paddingBody" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingTop', pixels:true})">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Padding-body left:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingLeft" name="paddingLeft" value="20" onchange="changeStyling([{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingLeft', pixels:true},{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'paddingLeft', pixels:true}])">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Padding-body right:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentPaddingRight" name="paddingRight" value="0" onchange="changeStyling([{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-inner', cssProperty:'paddingRight', pixels:true},{input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-header', cssProperty:'paddingRight', pixels:true}])">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Margin top form body (Input & Btn):
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="formMargin" value="70" name="margin" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-body', cssProperty:'marginTop', pixels:true})">
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Body border radius:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="exitIntentRadius" name="borderRadius" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'borderRadius', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Form</strong> <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                </li>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="collapse">
                    <li>
                        How many input fields?
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" value="2" class="inputQuantity" name="inputNumber" onchange="calculateInputs()" min="1" max="5">
                        <div class="formFieldInputs"></div>
                        <div class="btnAddinputs"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Type of form (presets):
                        <br>
                        <select class="exitIntentForm" name="typeOfForm" onchange="changeForm()">
                            <option value="onTop" selected>on top of each other</option>
                            <option value="inline">inline</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button text:
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" class="btnText" name="btnText" value="Inschrijven" onchange="changeText(this, '.button')">
                        <input type="color" class="btnTextColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'color', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" value="#ffffff">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button width:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnWidth" name="btnWidth" value="300" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'width', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button height:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnHeight" name="btnHeight" value="40" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'height', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button color:
                        <br>
                        <input type="color" class="btnColor" name="btnColor" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'backgroundColor', pixels:false})" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" value="#00CABA">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Button radius:
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="btnRadius" name="btnRadius" value="0" onchange="changeStyling({input:this, changeSelector:'.button', cssProperty:'borderRadius', pixels:true})">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Add privacy policy
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" class="privacyPolicy" name="privacyPolicy" onchange="showPrivacyPolicy()">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anchorlinks"></li>
                </ul>

                <li class="sidebar-category">
                    <strong>Exit intent html</strong>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <textarea cols="35" rows="10" class="html-viewer"></textarea>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-save btn-first" onclick="saveSettings()">Save settings</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-first" onclick="getHtml()">Get exit-intent html</button>
                </li>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Exit Intent -->
    <div class="exit-intent-container" style="margin-left: 20%;">
        <div class="content-overlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; background-color: #000; opacity: .5;"></div>

        <div class="exit-intent-wrapper">
            <span class="close-btn" onclick="closeExitIntent()"></span>
            <div class="exit-intent-content-wrapper">
                <div class="exit-intent-header-wrapper">
                    <h1 class="column exit-intent-header">Test</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="exit-intent-inner" style="font-size: 24px;">
                    <p class="column description">Register now to be the first to get all the updates</p>
                    <div class="exit-intent-body">
                        <div class="column">
                            <form action="" class="form">
                                <div class="inner-form">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="column">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="email-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <button class="button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css `.sidebar` for this one :

```
.sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 22%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option of changing sidebar background color to #eee and margin-bottom: 0px;

```
.sidebar ul {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GxojRX